# HQL query with map in java

Tags: java, dictionary, jpa, hql

How to create HQL query "select new map(A.a1, B.b1) from A left join B on A.a2=B.b2" where B could not exist? Now it returns correct result only when B exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. It was my fault. Incorrect condition in query: " where B.b3 = smth"